# Plot probability mass function of fractional hamming distance using Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, probability-density, hamming-distance

I would like to plot the pmf of a list of fractional hamming distance values (a list of numbers between 0 - 1). The following code shows what I did:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [round(random.uniform(0.2, 0.6),2) for i in range(1000)]
sns.distplot(x, hist=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The x is the sample list of fractional hamming distance values. And I want to show the distribution of these values. As the figure shows, the y-axis scale is wired. The pmf value should be within [0, 1] but in the figure it beyonded 1. I do not know how to solve this problem. Could you give me some suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really anything "weird" here. The plot shows the probability density function (pdf). Showing a probability mass function makes sense for discrete values. In case you want to treat your values discretely and plot a pmf, you could use `numpy.unique()`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.round(np.random.uniform(0.2, 0.6, 1000),2)

u, cnt = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)
plt.stem(u, cnt/len(x), use_line_collection=True)
plt.ylim(0,None)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your answer!